# How can i make Cassandra a Reaver?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

I'd like to make Cass a two handed reaver, but I'm not sure what I need to do, seeing as how her only skill set as of right now is Templar. I did a respec for her recently for pure DPS. She's currently lvl 12. How can I make Cass a reaver?

Comment: Are you asking how to give Cassandra the Reaver specialization or are you asking how to build her as two-handed DPS?

Answer (score 7):

All of your party members are locked into their specializations. You cannot turn Cassandra into a Reaver because she does not have access to that skill tree. You *can* give her two-handed weapons though.

Comment: Ah ok I see that now. Not a problem I suppose I can deal as is. Thanks for clearing that up for me. Definitely appreciate it!